# Get file name using hadoopFile

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using Spark 2.2 along with Scala 2.11 to parse a directory and transform data inside.

To handle ISO charset, I'm using hadoopFile like this :

```js
val inputDirPath = "myDirectory"
sc.hadoopFile[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](inputDirPath).map(pair => new String(pair._2.getBytes, 0, pair._2.getLength, "iso-8859-1")).map(ProcessFunction(_)).toDF
```

How can I get the file name of each row into the ProcessFunction ? 
ProcessFunction takes a String in param and return an object.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers includ your function ProcessFunction

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.{FileSplit, TextInputFormat}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD
val inputDirPath = "dataset.txt"
val textRdd = sc.hadoopFile[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](inputDirPath)
// cast TO HadoopRDD
val linesWithFileNames = rddHadoop.mapPartitionsWithInputSplit((inputSplit, iterator) => {
  val file = inputSplit.asInstanceOf[FileSplit]
  iterator.map(tuple => (file.getPath, new String(tuple._2.getBytes, 0, tuple._2.getLength, "iso-8859-1")))
}).map{case (path, line) =>  (path, ProcessFunction(line)}
```

Answer (score 1):

`val textRdd = sc.hadoopFile[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](inputDirPath)
    // cast TO HadoopRDD
        val linesWithFileNames = textRdd.asInstanceOf[HadoopRDD[LongWritable, Text]]
        .mapPartitionsWithInputSplit((inputSplit, iterator) => {
                val file = inputSplit.asInstanceOf[FileSplit]
                iterator.map(tuple => (file.getPath, tuple._2))
        }
   )
linesWithFileNames.foreach(println)`